# Palindrome C++ (strcpy)

Tags: c++, arrays, palindrome, c-strings

I tried to find a solution on internet but couldnt find anything similar to this. I am using strcpy and iteration to make a palindrome function in c++ everything is working fine but the strcpy section. I dont know how to solve it or what other alternative to use. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void palindrom(char[]);

int main()
{
   char binput[100];

   cout << "Hello please enter your word here: " << endl;    
   cin >> binput;
   palindrom(binput);

   system("pause");
   return 1;   
}

void palindrom(char binput[])
{
   int max= strlen(binput);
   char cinput[100];
   char dinput[100];

   for (int i=max, n=0; i>=0, n<=max; i--, n++)
      strcpy(dinput[n],binput[i]);

   cout << dinput << endl;

   if (strcmp(binput,dinput)==true)
      cout << "Is palindrome " << endl;
   else 
      cout << "Is not " << endl;
}
```

Comment: *"I am using strcpy"* - Use `std::string`.

Comment: Do you need it in c++ or is java ok?

Comment: @JürgenK. I need it in c++ thank you

Comment: @ChristianHackl can you please give an example? thank you

Comment: @Alfiebrown: Which C++ book are you using that does not cover such a basic thing as *strings*? Even a simple Google search for "c++ string" would already help...

Comment: Here you hava a video tutorial;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lg6n3S7Mcwg

Comment: Why do you need to even use `strcpy`?  You can discover if the word is a palindrome in-place, by just having two indices, one starting at the beginning of the string, the other starting at the end of the string.  Just compare the two characters at those indices -- if they are the same increment the first, decrement the second.  If they're not, then it isn't a palindrome and return.  Repeat this until the indices cross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this solves.Basically first just check the first letter of the word and the last. If they are not equal then they are not palindrome. If they are equal then proceed on by comparing from the front end character with their respective back ends.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int CheckPalindrome(char input[],int len);


int main()
{
  char input[100];
  int result,inpLen;


  cout<<"Enter Word:"<<endl;
  cin>>input;
  cout<<"Entered Word:"<<input<<endl;
  cout<<"Checking....."<<endl;
  inpLen=strlen(input);
  result=CheckPalindrome(input,inpLen);
  if(result == 1)
  {
    cout<<"Entered Word:"<<input<<" is a palindrome!"<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"Entered Word:"<<input<<" is not a palindrome!"<<endl;
  }

 return 0;
}

int CheckPalindrome(char input[],int len)
{

   int result;

   if(input[0] != input[len-1])
   {
      result = 0;
   }
   else
   {
   for(int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
   {
     if(input[i] == input[len-1-i])
     {
        result = 1;
     }
     else
     {
      result = 0;
      break;
     }
   }
  }

 return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not clear one what `strcpy` does. It copies an entire string from a source to a destination. You don't need that here. You need to make simple assignments.

Let's say your input is `"abc"`. I assume you want to create the string `"abccba"` from it.

Given the characters in the input:

```
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
```

you need to map them to the output array as:

```
binput[0]
|       binput[len-1]
|       |   binput[len-1]
| ....  |   |       binput[0]
|       |   | ....  |
v       v   v       v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | c | b | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now, translate that logic into code:

```
int len= strlen(binput);
char dinput[100];

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
{
   dinput[i] = binput[i];         // Takes care of the left side of the palindrome.
   dinput[2*len-i-1] = binput[i]; // Takes care of the right side of the palindrome
}

// Make sure to null terminate the output array.
dinput[2*len] = '\0';
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

You need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
{
   dinput[len-i-1] = binput[i];
}
dinput[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: Yes I understood the logic here, very powerful but i dont need "abccba" I need the dinput to be only "cba" to be able to compare later on with the binput and check if its a palindrome.  Thank you almost there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strcmp(word,strrev(word)==0)
```

Pallindrome

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize i to max-1 instead of max, the way you have it now it will copy the NULL terminator character '\0' to the first element of dinput which results in a 0 length string.

You will also need to make sure to NULL terminate dinput.  Try:

```
for (int i=max-1, n=0; i>=0, n<=max; i--, n++)
    dinput[n] = binput[i];

dinput[max] = '\0';
```

Comment: Yeah, that one is on me.  I went with the first obvious issue I saw and latched onto that.  Fixing up with working code.  /sigh

Comment: @Scott You are right about the null thanks. But the code still doesnt compile due to the strcpy.

Comment: Yeah, try now.  R Sahu was correct, I didn't validate everything.  It should be a simple copy.